# How do prepared casters use metamagic rods?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, metamagic

How do prepared casters like clerics and wizards use the metamagic rods?

- Are they only able to use the rod during the actual act of casting the spell?
- Are they able to use the rod when preparing spells so that their spell is prepared as the metamagic'ed version?
- Both are valid methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only the first option is valid: Having the metamagic rod does nothing while preparing spells. They are only effective if the caster is holding the rod while casting the spell.

From [d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/metamagic-rods):

> Metamagic rods hold the essence of a metamagic feat, allowing the user to apply metamagic effects to spells (but not spell-like abilities ) **as they are cast**.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: I was afraid of that, ok. Ideally both was what I had been hoping for.